# Regular Expression: Matching on either ques. mark or space in text

Tags: .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I'm working in .NET (C# 4.0); How do I write an expression that matches on an text that contains a '?' or a space '\S'?

```
GlennTest    (should not match)
Glenn?Test   (should match) 
Glenn Test   (should match) 
Glenn? Test  (should match) 
Glenn ?Test  (should match) 
?Glenn Test  (should match)
```

I am able to write expressions to find one, but combining them is giving me trouble.

CLARIFICATION:
I am clarifying my question because neither of the responses thus far worked.

I am writing an MVC app with the following RegExp Attribute on one of the properties, which appears to work as designed (doesnt allow spaces).

```
    [DataMember(Name="Job Code")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Job Code is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "Spaces are not allowed in the Job Code")]
    public string JobCode { get; set; }
```

That said, I want to extend this capability to disallow '?' question marks as well.

I also want the ability to test this in code, not on a MVC View using code like this:

```
public static bool IsValidCode(string code, out string message)
{
    message = "";
    const string NO_QMS_REG_EXP = @"^\?*$";
    const string NO_SPACES_REG_EXP = @"^\S*$";

    var expr1 = new Regex(NO_QMS_REG_EXP);
    var expr2 = new Regex(NO_SPACES_REG_EXP);
    if (expr1.IsMatch(code))
    {
        message = "Code cannot contain a question mark";
        return false;
    }
    if (expr2.IsMatch(code))
    {
        message = "Code cannot contain a space";
        return false;
    }
    // TODO: One expression that validates both simulatenously??
    return true;
}
```

MVC3 question: Can I programmatically execute the properties Regex Attrib validation?

Comment: `\S` isn't a space, it's just the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try

```
^[^?\s]*$
```

This matches any string that contains neither spaces nor question marks.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
[\s?]+
```

See [Positive character group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx)

`+` is for *one or more instance*, since you're saying "Glenn? Test" should match. Change that to something like `{1,2}` if you want it to be exactly one or two instances, as in said string.

```
Glenn[\s?]+Test
```

If you just want to verify that a space or a question mark occurs anywhere in the string, a simple `[\s?]` will do.

**Update**

What you're doing is to *validate* the string, that is, check that it *does* meet a given requirement. The error message is shown if it *doesn't*. Your current regex, checking for `^\S*$` does not look for a string, that says "from start (`^`) to end (`$`), all characters must match the pattern `\S*`, which is zero or more instances of *anything-but-a-space*".

You could update your pattern accordingly:

```
^[^\s?]*$
```

Which would say "the entire string (again, `^...$`) must consist only of characters that are *not* in the current set (`[^...])`".

Answer (score 1):

After the update, you need this:

```
^[^\s?]*$
```

see it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vdv8)

`[^\s?]` is a negated character class that will match any character, except whitespace and the question mark.

For the part of the online testing tools:

- [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), my favourite
- http://regexstorm.net/tester, .NET based
- [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/), Ruby based
- http://www.myregextester.com, different engines can be choosen, can also provide source code for different languages.
- [Regular Expression  Analyzer](http://xenon.stanford.edu/%7Exusch/regexp/analyzer.html), takes a regex and provides an explanation for each part

There is also an [answer on Programmers by me](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/108141/30042), where I list useful (mostly online) Regex resources (this is my subjective list, what has been useful for me, by no means complete)

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive I updated my answer and the Regexr link according to your update.

Comment: I already upvoted your answer before your edit - too bad I can't do it again :)